# Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\tempkey.rsa'

Tags: azure, .net-core, identityserver4

This is causing the issue in Startup.cs:

> services.AddIdentityServer()
>                   .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()

I tried to manually insert the tempkey.rsa folder, but it, doesn't fix the issue.

Please advise me on how to proceed with this issue?

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\tempkey.rsa'.
>   System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share,
>   FileOptions options)
>
> ```
> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\tempkey.rsa'.
> ```
>
> System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share,
>   FileOptions options) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions
>   options) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string path, bool append,
>   Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string
>   path) System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string path, string contents)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsCrypto.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(IIdentityServerBuilder
>   builder, bool persistKey, string filename)
>   IdentityServer.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>   in Startup.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Comment: does it happen after publishing your application?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

tempkey.rsa is not a folder. it is a temp key which identity server sign it's tokens with that.
when you run your application this temp key generate automatically at projects root folder. temporary you can paste [this temp key](https://gofile.io/?c=FDPtsh) beside your .csproj file and see it'll working very well.

Comment: This does not make any sense. The error is file not found even though it is right there